# How to make an unopenable QIODevice

Tags: qt, unit-testing, io

I'm trying to test a class that uses a `QIODevice`. In actuality, the object will probably use a `QFile`, but for my unit test I'd prefer to use a `QBuffer` for speed. Dependency injection and polymorphism combine to get me what I want.

I have a problem, however. My class constructor looks like this:

```
Object::Object(QIODevice& source)
{
   if(!source.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
   {
      qDebug("Object: Could not open source.");
   }
}
```

Then in my test I check for the message:

```
void TestObject::printsErrorOnOpenFailure()
{
   QTest::ignoreMessage(QtDebugMsg, "Object: Could not open source.");
   QBuffer buffer;
   Object obj(buffer);
}
```

Unfortunately, open still seems to succeed even without a `QByteArray` to operate on. What's the best way to give my object a `QIODevice` that I know it can't open?

Comment: Why do you need a pointer to your `QIODevice`?

Comment: Because I didn't think things through carefully enough when I simplified the setup code for the example. I'll remove that, as it's unneccessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make `QBuffer::open()` to return false **(*)**. So you can't use `QBuffer` in your scenario.

But what about sub-classing and just overwriting `open()` to always return false?

```
class UnopenableDevice : public QBuffer {
public:
    bool open(QIODevice::OpenMode m) { return false; }
};
```

---

**(*)** At least not using the flags `WriteOnly` and/or `ReadOnly`. Passing invalid flags is the only possibility to make it return false. Quoting Qt 4.8.0 sources:

*corelib/io/qbuffer.cpp:*

```
332 bool QBuffer::open(OpenMode flags)              
333 {
334     Q_D(QBuffer);
335 
336     if ((flags & (Append | Truncate)) != 0)
337         flags |= WriteOnly;
338     if ((flags & (ReadOnly | WriteOnly)) == 0) {
339         qWarning("QBuffer::open: Buffer access not specified");
340         return false;    //  <----- only possibility to return false!
341     }
342 
343     if ((flags & Truncate) == Truncate)
344         d->buf->resize(0);
345     d->ioIndex = (flags & Append) == Append ? d->buf->size() : 0;
346 
347     return QIODevice::open(flags);
348 }
```

*corelib/io/qiodevice.cpp:*

```
540 bool QIODevice::open(OpenMode mode)
541 {
542     Q_D(QIODevice);
543     d->openMode = mode;
544     d->pos = (mode & Append) ? size() : qint64(0);
545     d->buffer.clear();
546     d->accessMode = QIODevicePrivate::Unset;
547     d->firstRead = true;
548 #if defined QIODEVICE_DEBUG
549     printf("%p QIODevice::open(0x%x)\n", this, quint32(mode));
550 #endif
551     return true;
552 }
```

Comment: That can't be instantiated. QIODevice::readData and QIODevice::writeData are pure virtual. I replaced the inheritance from QIODevice with inheritance from QBuffer and removed the unnecessary constructor.

Comment: Another possibility would be to use a `QFile("")`; this shouldn't be openable, too.

Comment: If I have to include an entirely separate class, I might as well use the (very understandable) UnopenableDevice. But that QFile hint might help me some day in the future. Anyways, I've accepted your answer. The commented Qt source code in particular was a nice touch.